# How can I avoid the Cinemachine camera turning with my 2D character?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm rotating my `2D` character from right to left depending on where the player wants to go. The problem is that the `Cinemachine` virtual camera is turning when the player goes left. How could I avoid that?

I have looked if there is a configuration in the `Cinemachine` virtual camera to freeze the `Y` rotation or something like that, but I have not found it.

Comment: Provide more info about your Cinemachine camera Body and Aim settings

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned it, but I assume you're rotating your character's `Y` axis from `0` to `180` degrees and vice versa. This is probably not the best way to do it, as it give you both troubles with the `Cinemachine` and position's `Z` axis.

I'd suggest you flipping your player's `SpriteManager` on `X` axis, which prevents any troubles with `Cinemachine`.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public enum DirectionX
{
    Right,
    Left
}

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 10f;

    public DirectionX currDir = DirectionX.Right;

    private SpriteRenderer _spriteRenderer;

    private void Start()
    {
        // get sprite renderer component from our player
        _spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // get new move direction (1, -1 or 0)
        float moveDir = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        // new direction shouldn't be 0
        if (moveDir != 0)
        {
            // get float (1 or -1) from the direction enum
            float dir = GetDirection(currDir);

            // translate transform to right (1 * 1) or left (1 * -1) according to the direction
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * moveDir * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            // if new direction isn't the same as the old one, flip the player and assign new current direction
            if (moveDir != dir)
            {
                Flip();
                currDir = GetDirection(moveDir);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Flip() => _spriteRenderer.flipX = !_spriteRenderer.flipX;

    private float GetDirection(DirectionX direction) =>
        direction == DirectionX.Right ? 1f : -1f;

    private DirectionX GetDirection(float direction) =>
        direction == 1 ? DirectionX.Right : DirectionX.Left;
}
```

We got to store our current direction, which you can do using a:

- `boolean`, where `true` is right and `false` is left
- `float`, where `1f` is right and `-1f` is left
- a custom `enum`, where `enum.Right` is, obviously, right and `enum.Left` is left

I like to use an `enum` for readability, even if we have to convert it back to `float` and vice versa.

We check for a new move direction and flip our player if it's not the same as the old one. Make sure to assign the direction correctly in the `Inspector`. So if the player is looking left by default, the direction should be `Left` too.

[image]